# Let a program execute another program over ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi3, ssh-tunnel

As mentioned in the title I want to let a program execute a program over `ssh`. Means I have a program on my Linux laptop which shall execute a file lying on my Raspberry Pi. Something like:

```
my_Program_local ./pi@192.168.x.xx:22/Path_to_ssh_file_on_Raspberry_Pi".
```

Appreciate every hint.

Comment: What is "my_Program_local"? Is it a Shell script? Or is it a C program?

Comment: It is a c program. It writes data to stdin. The file on the raspberry is inquiring a read over stdin and the c program writes to it.

Comment: It is not possible to write to stdin. It is just possible to read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

If your C program writes to stdout, then you can pipe the output into the remote program on your Raspi this way:

```
my_Program_local | ssh pi@192.168.x.xx /Path_to_ssh_file_on_Raspberry_Pi
```

Example:

```
base64 <<<'Hello World!' | ssh pi@raspi 'base64 -u'
```